# Netbeans (7.0) HTML 'dynamic' code templates

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I know how to define static, standard code templates in NetBeans and I am wondering whether it's possible to define more customized and dynamic templates.

For example, when i type `div.className` to generate me a HTML `<div>` element with the class I specify.

Answer (score 1):

Start netbeans and go-to: `Tools->Plugins` menu,`Available Plugins` tab, then search for `Zen Coding` hit install.

type: `div.className` and hit: `ctrl+alt+n` to get: `<div class="className">`

You will notice the new `Edit->Zen Coding` menu.
Installation & usage: https://github.com/lorenzos/ZenCodingNetBeansPlugin#readme

Read more about Zen Coding at: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/